# How to change the background-image of an HTML element with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

as the title says, I want to change the background-image property of an HTML element (a simple div), using pure JavaScript.

I have a separate JS file for the script code, which targets the element and although it supposedly updates the background-image property, the new image is not showing in the element.

```js
function changeImg1() {
  document.getElementById("mapbox").style.backgroundImage = "url('newimage.png')";

  document.getElementById("mapbox").style.backgroundSize = "contain";

  document.getElementById("mapbox").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

  document.getElementById("mapbox").style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

```css
.map-box {
  height: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  left: 55%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(image.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-box" id="mapbox">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
      <li onclick="changeImg1()" id="dpt-1">
        Click Me!
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>;
```

At this point, the default image set on CSS vanishes, but the new one specified in JavaScript does not appear. The background does turn black however. Any ideas ?

Comment: Use the browser "Network" debug tab to see if an HTTP request is being made for the new image URL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. 
Alright, so I checked that and I saw that a 404 error was occurring due to JavaScript not seeing the picture. I updated the image path with the full path, starting from "C:", in the JS function, and although the 404 error is fixed, the new image is still not shown.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the same code with an image stored on a remote server, works normally (despite a short delay of a few seconds before its appearance). E.g.: 
         document.getElementById("thisdiv").style.backgroundImage = 
     "url('https://www.veracode.com/sites/default/files/secure-random-number-
     generator-java%20%281%29.jpg')";
This works, but a local path ("C:/etc/etc/newimage.png") doesn't seem to work.